# ASUS ROG G551JK Backlight

Tags: asus, backlight, mate

I am new linux user and I have problem with my backlight. When I press the combination for turning it off, this appears on the screen.

[image]
I use Ubuntu MATE 14.04

```
samuel@samuel-G551JK:~$ ls /sys/class/backlight
intel_backlight
```

Now it is disabled, when I enable it, I can't turn it off.
It's off when on battery, not plugged in.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls /sys/class/backlight` terminal command.

Comment: Can you increase/decrease brightness using buttons?

Comment: No, nothing happens.

Comment: But volume, touchpad, "make monitor black" works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/quiet splash/quiet splash acpi_osi=/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot. The keys must work.

You will probably need to create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with this content

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Seems like I don't have gedit, and my mouse sometimes goes crazy, but one touchpad click makes it normal. I'll use nano instead of gedit.

Comment: I made all that text as a command. It does same.

Comment: "The keys must work." That's an order! =)

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich Common, give him an upvote, you have enough reps ;)

Comment: Actually, I didn't have. :P

Comment: @A.B. I have too many today either way. And I made a lot of kernel programming to fix this. But it was not accepted upstream ;-) So it IS an order.

Comment: @Pilot6 Wow more than 300  today, not bad

Comment: The problem is here again.

Comment: I can control everything except backlight.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich What do you mean?  When did this happen? After reboot? Give output again of `ls /sys/class/backlight`.

Comment: After second reboot.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich Check your /etc/default/grub file and add additional solution that I added.

Comment: I'll tell you, when I will boot Ubuntu again.

Comment: intel_backlight is not installed

Comment: Now it is disabled, when I enable it, I can't turn it off.

Comment: Your answer solved it once. Some update solved it few months ago. I accept your answer.